# Unique column values on a combination of columns in R Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

**Problem:**
I have a dataframe (df)

```
    Source  Source1  Target   Target.1 Target.2 Target.3
1   SDB1    SDB2     TDB1     TDB2     TDB2     TDB2
2   STB1    STB2     TTB1     TTB2     TTB2     TTB3
3   SCOL1   SCOL2    TCOL1    TCOL2    TCOL3    TCOL4
```

I want a resultant dataframe which would look like (What I want is to get Unique pairs from rows 1 and 2):

```
X1    X2
SDB1  STB1
SDB2  STB2
TDB1  TTB1
TDB2  TTB2,TTB3
```

**What I tried**

I was able to get this till now and not sure how to proceed from here:

```
!(duplicated(t(df[c(1,2),])))

[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: This one would be more helpful with a reproducible example: check out:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  I recommend dput

Comment: I am having a hard time to understand your question. Can you elaborate your situation?

Comment: @MatthewR I editted the question to add more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can subset first two rows of dataframe and do `aggregate`

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(t(df[1:2, ]), row.names = FALSE)
names(df1) <- paste0('X', 1:2)
aggregate(X2~X1, df1, function(x) toString(unique(x)))

#    X1         X2
#1 SDB1       STB1
#2 SDB2       STB2
#3 TDB1       TTB1
#4 TDB2 TTB2, TTB3
```

---

Using `dplyr`, we can do :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 slice(1:2) %>%
 t %>%
 as.data.frame() %>%
 group_by(V1) %>%
 summarise(V2 = toString(unique(V2)))
```

Comment: this is what I needed

Comment: what if i want add value of X2 (i.g. TTB2,TTB3 in last row above) as new columns to dataframe. ( new colnames would be existing cols + TTB2 and TTB3 with TT2 TTB3 having blank values) is there a way?

Comment: @Deep Perhaps, you mean `df %>%
  slice(1:2) %>%
  t %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  summarise(V2 = toString(unique(V2))) %>%
  mutate(V3 = replace(V2, V2 != "TTB2, TTB3", ""), 
         V2 = replace(V2, V2 == "TTB2, TTB3", ""))` ?